# Datalist does not show values after space (not showing whole string value)

Tags: java, html, servlets

Using servlets, I am trying to get datalist from database. But datalist does not show the whole string value.
Example: "Computer Science" displayed as "Computer" in dayalist options. Values are displayed correctly in the console, Eg:"Computer Science"

```
    out.println("<input list=\"dept12\" id=\"dept1\" > <datalist id=\"dept12\">");
while(itr.hasNext())
{
Long key=(Long) itr.next();
out.println("<option  value="+map.get(key)+" id="+key+">");
out.println("</option>");
}
out.println("</datalist>");
```

Comment: What is `itr`, is it result set

Comment: try and debug it, see what is contained in map at the value of the key

Comment: Values are displayed correctly in the console, Eg:"Computer Science"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did an mistake in this line:

```
out.println("<option  value="+map.get(key)+" id="+key+">");
```

I think it must be:

```
out.println("<option  value=\""+map.get(key)+"\" id=\""+key+"\">");
```